# Mail alert with message "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names"

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
#Purpose = Backup 
#Created on 15-10-2015
#START
#cp -b /etc/rc.local $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/rc.local

TIME=`date +"%d%b%y_%H%M%S"`                    
MKDIRNAME=`date +"%d%b%y"`                      
FOBACKUP=$(date +'%d%b%y' -d 'last month')          
DESDIR="/usr/local/backup/"             

FILENAME1="filebin_$TIME.tar.gz"                    
FILENAME2="openvpn_$TIME.tar.gz"
FILENAME3="script_$TIME.tar.gz"


SRCDIR1="/usr/local/bin/"                   
SRCDIR2="/etc/openvpn/"
SRCDIR3="/var/script/"

mkdir -m 0755 $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME                 

tar -cpzf $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME1 $SRCDIR1         
tar -cpzf $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME2 $SRCDIR2
tar -cpzf $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME3 $SRCDIR3
cp -b /etc/rc.local $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/rc.local
cp -b /etc/crontab $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/crontab

if [ -d "$DESDIR$FOBACKUP" ]; then
   echo "file $FOBACKUP exist and was deleted!"
   rm -rf $DESDIR$FOBACKUP
fi

#END
```

However, I keep receiving mails everyday  - after cron runs this script - with this message:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

How can I do the changes on this script in order to not receive this alert?

Answer (score 3):

`tar` issues this warning and removes the leading slashes for safety reasons. Extracting an archive containing absolute paths, even without root permissions, can have the unintended consequence of overwriting current files with old.

The following steps should eliminate your undesirable output, correct the problem that `tar` was warning about, and continue to allow you to see important error messages. The script becomes more consistent because the variables correctly reflect the contents of the archive.

1. *Remove any leading '/' characters from the source directory names*.

   ```
   SRCDIR1="usr/local/bin/"                   
   SRCDIR2="etc/openvpn/"
   SRCDIR3="var/script/"
   ```
2. *Use the `-C /` option of `tar`* to cause `tar` to change directory to `/` before archiving.  If this option were not available, you would change directory to `/` before issuing the `tar` command.

   ```
   tar -C / -cpzf $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME1 $SRCDIR1         
   tar -C / -cpzf $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME2 $SRCDIR2
   tar -C / -cpzf $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME3 $SRCDIR3
   ```

Comment: I love this answer, it explains well why the message is there. Is there any other alternative ways of doing this without removing '/' ? It seems like my variable depends on this leading character.

Comment: @MaXi32   If your *variable* depends on the leading character, then you could modify the SRCDIR vars only on the tar command lines, for example by replacing `$SRCDIR1` with `${SRCDIR1##/}` or with `$(echo "$SRCDIR1" | sed 's,^/*,,')`

If you absolutely must store filenames in the archive with absolute path names, you can use the `--absolute-names` or `-P` option to cause `tar` *not* to strip leading slashes from file names.  This works both for extraction and creation of archives, similar to -C (the preferred method).

Answer (score -1):

Look into [pipe redirects](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) and the difference between [stdin, stdout & stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

The following will address it;

```
tar -cpzf $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME1 $SRCDIR1 2> /dev/null
```

EDIT:
Because of 'safety' concerns about using '2> /dev/null' to redirect stderr to /dev/null here are some other possible methods of 'safely' performing the tar operations while NOT using the '-C /' option to move to '/' within the fs first. Which IMHO is a security problem as it stands as if the archive is extracted from '/' it would overwrite the current filesystem with the content of the archive.

Some alternatives:

An alternative to RobertL's suggestion (move to the $SRCDIR first)

```
%> tar -cpzf -C $SRCDIR1 $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME1 $SRCDIR1
```

Use redirection for stderr, capture stdout but still check for errors using `$?`

```
%> output=$((tar -cpzf $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME1 $SRCDIR1) 2> /dev/null)
%> [ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "An error occurred with tar"
%> echo $output
```

Or you can always use relative &/or absolute paths (see man `pwd`)

```
%> $((tar -cpzf $DESDIR$MKDIRNAME/$FILENAME1 $(pwd)/$SRCDIR1) 2&>1)
```

Comment: Not a good idea.  This could hide important error messages.

Comment: If written correctly you would simply test the results as [ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "error". But then again that wasn't the question that was asked. Thanks for the down vote though :)

Comment: That would still not be written correctly.  That hides the error also.  `2>/dev/null` is almost never a good idea.  This is actually a dangerous practice that should be discouraged, not encouraged.

Comment: Could you provide some background information and/or resources as to the reasons? If I am wrong I would love to know why

Comment: The reason is because when you use '2>/dev/null', _all_ error messages are discarded.  If `tar` failed, the information about why it failed would be unavailable forever.  In this case it was a warning, but also explained that the archive did not contain what was requested.  So we look at why `tar` issued the warning and make better code to eliminate the message.  Can you defend `2>/dev/null`? When would that be a good idea?

Comment: Other then replacing it with [ $? ] && echo "error" or similar following a call to tar? No. I suppose an alternative (or safer alternative) would be to capture the output i.e. $((tar -c archive.tar /path) 2&>1) which is why I provided information regarding research on stdin, stdout, stderr & pipe redirections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30844/discussion-between-robertl-and-jas).